# How would I add "You got it right in ... guesses!"

Tags: java

I need to add "You got it right in ... guesses!" but I'm not exactly sure how. Can someone please explain to me how to do this in java?

I would like it to display a println at the end saying how many tries it took for the user to get the number correct.

```
import java.util.*;

public class prog210c
{
  public static void main()
  {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random rn = new Random();

      int randomNum = rn.nextInt(90) + 10;

      System.out.println("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100");

      while (true) {
          System.out.print("What do you think it is? ");
          int guess = sc.nextInt();

          if(guess < randomNum)
          {
              System.out.println("Higher--Try Again");
          }

          else if(guess > randomNum)
          {
              System.out.println("Lower--Try Again");
          }

          else if(guess == randomNum)
          {
              System.out.println("Correct!");
              break;
          }

          else
          {
              System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 100");
          }
        }

      //System.out.println("You got it right in " + + " guesses");

  } //end main
} //end class
```

Comment: so you wanna show the get it right message to an user if it did it right?

Comment: I want it to say at the end how many guesses it took to get it right. Added a comment where I would like it to output it.

Comment: You need to have attempted something and not just look for a solution from others. Show your attempts, debug through the code, and then post any errors or exceptions you are getting.

Comment: Unrelated issue, but your last else block is dead code.

Answer (score 1):

Just create some int variable to store your number of attempts in and increment it every time you read in a guess.

```
int attempts = 0;

System.out.println("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100");

while (true) {
    System.out.print("What do you think it is? ");
    int guess = sc.nextInt();
    attempts++;

    /**
     * The rest of your loop code here.
     */
}

System.out.println("You got it right in " + attempts + " guesses");
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is declared a counter integer, and in your logic increment it every time the user attempts.

```
int guessCounter = 0;

while(true) // Also do not use an infinite while loop, have an expression that can be terminated
{
...obtain input

if(guess < randomNum)
{
...
guessCounter++;

}
else if (guess > randomNum){
....
guessCounter++;
}

System.Out.println("The number of attempts " + guessCounter);
}
```

Comment: there is not println in Java. there is System.out.println

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating a variable to store the number of tries, like an `int`, and then add one to the `int` every time the user guesses, by using `variable++`:

```
  public static void main(){
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random rn = new Random();

      int tries = 0;

      int randomNum = rn.nextInt(90) + 10;

      System.out.println("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100");

      while(true){
          System.out.print("What do you think it is? ");
          int guess = sc.nextInt();


          //Rest of your code here
        }

      System.out.println("You got it right in " + tries + " guesses");

  }
```

and if you want to go even above and beyond, you could make it so it says *You got it right in 1 **guess*** instead of it saying *You got it right in 1 **guesses***, if the user gets the number correct on their first try. We can do this by using the ternary Java operator, which is pretty much a compact if-statement:

```
String s = (tries == 1 ? "guess" : "guesses");
```

What this is pretty much doing is: `if this is true ? do this : else do this`

Now we can change the *You got it right in...* part of your program to say *guess* instead of *guesses* if the user guesses the number on their first try:

```
String s = (tries == 1 ? "guess" : "guesses");
System.out.println("You got it right in " + tries + "" + s);
```